# When i use VS2022 MFC, there is an error 0x00007FFEF70E4FD3

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2022

When i use GetMenu()->GetSubMenu(2)-> 'xxx', there is an error:
**Exception thrown at 0x00007FFEF70E4FD3 (mfc140d.dll) (in Menu.exe): 0xC0000005: An access violation occurred while reading location 0x0000000000008.**

I added the above code at the end of the OnCreate function in the CMainFrame class.

```
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct){

GetMenu()->GetSubMenu(2)->CheckMenuItem(0, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_CHECKED);
}
```

Comment: One of those pointers is NULL. Run it in the debugger and when it crashes uses the call stack to find your code then examine the variables and state of the program to figure out why. It can be a good idea to break that code up into multiple statements so you can assign the result to a variable and check for NULL before using it.

Comment: Thank you. As you said, it's true that GetMenu() got a null pointer. I found two solutions:
1. Change the value of 'CMFCMenuBar m_wndMenuBar' in 'Mainfrm.h mainfrm.cpp.' Delete the code of the. The compilation is successful.
2. When creating a project, select 'Use a classic menu'.

Answer (score 1):

3.Class "Cxxxx" does not have member "GetContextMenuManager" 'GetContextMenuManager': is not a member of'Cxxxx' After analysis, it is found that the current class Cxxx is inherited from CWinApp, which does not have the GetContextMenuManager function. If you select Use Menu Bar and Toolbar when creating a project, no error is reported. After analysis, it is found that Cxxx is derived from CWinAppEx. It has the GetContextMenuManager() member method. Therefore, do not report an error, manually modify the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that GetMenu() got a null pointer. I found two solutions:

1. Change the value of **CMFCMenuBar m_wndMenuBar** in **Mainfrm.h mainfrm.cpp**. Delete the code of the. The compilation is successful.
2. When creating a project, select **Use a classic menu**.